# Dropdown links do not display on hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

After a long break from HTML/CSS, I recently created a menu with dropdown links using a method I have used once before, and was surprised to find that this application of them is not working.

I used this

```
ul li:hover ul{ display:block;}
```

to "turn on" my menus when hovering, but they simply never appear. I have tried adding div tags around various blocks of code to no avail. What tricks am I missing?

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qccs4mLL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html isn't align with your css selector.

```
ul.menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
```

There isn't any `ul` element that is direct child of `li` element. You can change your html so `ul` is direct child of `li` element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 8em;
  /*width of each link*/
}
/*format list*/

ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.menu {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #454545;
}
ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
ul.menu li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
ul.menu ul {
  background: #555;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
ul.menu li:hover {
  background: red;
}
ul.menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Heading-->
  <!--Should change when scrolled down/on mobile-->

  <h1 class="heading">Title</h1>

  <!--Create Menus-->
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">link1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">sublink1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!--menu options with sub options have dropdown on computer, may unfold with tap on mobile or just be a click since they all go to one page maybe? maybe go with unfolding.-->

      <li><a href="#">link2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">sublink1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sublink2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sublink3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sublink4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#">link3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```